# How does a web application update live counter/timers on the front end?

Tags: web-applications, asynchronous, web

I've been looking at some penny auction sites and trying to figure out how they work. These sites have live timers showing how long an auction has before the latest bidder wins. The timers reset any time someone bids or to give some more time when the timer approaches 0.

I've looked at the firebug console to see if any HTTP requests are being made and some site send a GET request every second to get the updated timers, but other sites don't. The timers (independently from other timers) get refreshed at random times without any requests being sent to the server. How do they achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how exactly the website you are inspecting is implementing this, but I believe it's possible with websockets. http://www.websocket.org/echo.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like : http://codecanyon.net/item/realtime-online-users/3740135 ?

Comment: Not really. The purpose wasn't to monitor user activity.